# pip uninstall jupyter : Doesnt work

Tags: pip, ipython, jupyter

I had done pip install --user jupyter. 
It install jupyter in .local/. 
I uninstalled it with : pip uninstall jupyter
It seemed to uninstall and whic jupyter returns nothing.

However, all files still reside under .local. pip list does show ipython and also ipython-genutils. 
And when I run .local/bin/ipython it runs.

Could you tell me how to uninstall jupyter?
Thanks
T

Comment: @Rao, you are answering a different question. @Terry, `pip` only uninstalls the program you specify. It does not automatically remove dependencies. So if you want to remove ipython as well, you have to uninstall it explicitly.

Comment: @cel, thank you for point my mistake. Looks, I over looked, apologies.

Comment: @Rao, no problem, you can simply delete wrong comments :)